# Proving that a function is integrable if and only if it is right continuous at $0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I'm having trouble, in particular, proving the converse of the following statement: Let $f$ be a bounded function on $[-1,1]$, and let $\alpha$ be defined as $\alpha=0 \text{ if } x<0$ and $\alpha=1 \text{ if } x>0$, $\alpha(0)=0$.  Prove that $f\in \mathcal{R}(\alpha)$ if and only if $f(0^+)=f(0)$.

I have the proof for the forward direction as follows:

$\alpha$ is a constant function everywhere except at $0$, and so we have that $\alpha(x_1)-\alpha(x_2) >0 \iff (x_1 \leq 0\text{ and }x_2 >0)$.

Let $P$ be a partition of $[-1,1]$.  Then $P$ contains at most one interval $[a,b]$ such that $a\leq 0 <b$.  Therefore $U(P,f,\alpha)=\left(\max_{x\in[a,b]} f(x)\right)\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)=\left(\max_{x\in[a,b]} f(x)\right)(1)-0=\left(\max_{x\in[a,b]} f(x)\right)$ and $L(P,f,\alpha)=\left(\min_{x\in[a,b]} f(x)\right)\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)=\left(\max_{x\in[a,b]} f(x)\right)(1)-0=\left(\max_{x\in[a,b]} f(x)\right)$.

Let $\varepsilon >0$.  Then, if $f\in \mathcal{R}(\alpha)$, for $b-a$ small we have that $\max_{x\in[a,b]} f(x)-\max_{x\in[a,b]} f(x) < \varepsilon$.  Therefore, $f(0^{+})=f(0)$, since $b\neq 0$.

As for the converse, I think the general idea is that if $f$ is continuous, we can find $b-a$ is sufficiently small so that this holds, but I'm having difficulty formalizing this.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does $\mathcal{R}(\alpha)$ stand for?

Comment: Sorry I forgot that -- $\mathcal{R}(\alpha)$ is the collection of all Riemann-Stieltjes integrable functions with respect to $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x \in [0, \delta]$ you are going to have $\max  \, f - \min \,  f < \varepsilon$, and you know this positive number $\delta$ exists because you assume $f\in \mathcal{R}(\alpha)$.

Now assume $f$ is right continuous at $0$. Then there exists $2\delta>0$ so that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $x, y \in [0, \delta]$. Since $[0, \delta]$ is compact we know that $\max f, \min f$ exist and that $\max \, f - \min \, f <\epsilon$.